# How to get an hourly forecast from mean, max forecast and historicals

Tags: time-series, forecasting, modeling

I have hourly historical temperature curve for a month say January. I also have a monthly peak and a monthly mean forecast for March 2024 (two values). Using this - How can we get an hourly forecast curve - such that the mean and peak is the same as the prediction.
A simple transformation would also work.

I thought of scaling by mean or the peak values but am finding difficult to fit the 2nd variable in an intuitive way.

Comment: You could simply aggregate the historical data on a monthly level, and then find the month which has similar mean/peak compared to your 2024 forecast, and just paste that as your forecast.